# How to get a US state name from valid US zip code in PHP?

Tags: php, function, zipcode

I've one valid US zip code value. Now I want to get the state name in United States to which this zip code belongs. I'm not storing these state names or zip codes in my database. I want to get this state name dynamically. This process should be faster, it should not take much time in getting the state name.

I googled a lot about this but couldn't get the satisfactory answer. Can someone please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes a satisfactory answer? There are lists of postcodes and their states available, you could load one up and read out the state.

Comment: Some ZIP codes are in more than one state.  You need the full address to be deterministic.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another API. Its free and easy to use.

http://www.zippopotam.us/

All you need to do is call the URL in following format and you'll get the response in JSON format.

[http://api.zippopotam.us/country/zipcode](http://api.zippopotam.us/us/90210)

Comment: Just found this while looking for something else, +1 for the bookmark.

Answer (score 7):

Fast, standalone, no internet required, no-API code (87 lines):

```
function zipToState($zipcode)
{
  /* 000 to 999 */
  $zip_by_state = [
    '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', 'NY', 'PR', 'PR', 'VI', 'PR', 'MA', 'MA', 'MA', 
    'MA', 'MA', 'MA', 'MA', 'MA', 'MA', 'MA', 'MA', 'MA', 'MA', 'MA', 'MA', 'MA', 
    'MA', 'MA', 'RI', 'RI', 'NH', 'NH', 'NH', 'NH', 'NH', 'NH', 'NH', 'NH', 'NH', 
    'ME', 'ME', 'ME', 'ME', 'ME', 'ME', 'ME', 'ME', 'ME', 'ME', 'ME', 'VT', 'VT', 
    'VT', 'VT', 'VT', 'MA', 'VT', 'VT', 'VT', 'VT', 'CT', 'CT', 'CT', 'CT', 'CT', 
    'CT', 'CT', 'CT', 'CT', 'CT', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 
    'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ', 'AE', 
    'AE', 'AE', 'AE', 'AE', 'AE', 'AE', 'AE', 'AE', '--', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 
    'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 
    'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 
    'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 
    'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 
    'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 
    'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 
    'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', '--', 'PA', 'PA', 
    'PA', 'PA', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DC', 'VA', 'DC', 'DC', 'DC', 'DC', 'MD', 'MD', 
    'MD', 'MD', 'MD', 'MD', 'MD', '--', 'MD', 'MD', 'MD', 'MD', 'MD', 'MD', 'VA', 
    'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 
    'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 'VA', 
    'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 
    'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', 'WV', '--', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 
    'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 
    'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC', 'SC', 'SC', 'SC', 'SC', 'SC', 'SC', 'SC', 'SC', 'SC', 
    'SC', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 
    'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 
    'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 
    'FL', 'FL', 'AA', 'FL', 'FL', '--', 'FL', '--', 'FL', 'FL', '--', 'FL', 'AL', 
    'AL', 'AL', '--', 'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 
    'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'TN', 'TN', 'TN', 'TN', 'TN', 'TN', 'TN', 
    'TN', 'TN', 'TN', 'TN', 'TN', 'TN', 'TN', 'TN', 'TN', 'MS', 'MS', 'MS', 'MS', 
    'MS', 'MS', 'MS', 'MS', 'MS', 'MS', 'MS', 'MS', 'GA', '--', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 
    'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 
    'KY', 'KY', 'KY', '--', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', 'KY', '--', 
    '--', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 
    'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 
    'OH', 'OH', 'OH', 'OH', '--', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 
    'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'MI', 
    'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 
    'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'MI', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 
    'IA', 'IA', '--', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', '--', '--', '--', 
    'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', '--', 'WI', 'WI', 'WI', 
    '--', 'WI', 'WI', '--', 'WI', 'WI', 'WI', 'WI', 'WI', 'WI', 'WI', 'WI', 'WI', 
    'WI', 'WI', 'WI', 'WI', 'MN', 'MN', '--', 'MN', 'MN', 'MN', 'MN', 'MN', 'MN', 
    'MN', 'MN', 'MN', 'MN', 'MN', 'MN', 'MN', 'MN', 'MN', '--', 'DC', 'SD', 'SD', 
    'SD', 'SD', 'SD', 'SD', 'SD', 'SD', '--', '--', 'ND', 'ND', 'ND', 'ND', 'ND', 
    'ND', 'ND', 'ND', 'ND', '--', 'MT', 'MT', 'MT', 'MT', 'MT', 'MT', 'MT', 'MT', 
    'MT', 'MT', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 
    'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', '--', 'IL', 'IL', 
    'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'IL', 'MO', 'MO', '--', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', 
    'MO', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', '--', '--', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', '--', 
    'MO', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', '--', 'KS', 'KS', 'KS', 
    '--', 'KS', 'KS', 'KS', 'KS', 'KS', 'KS', 'KS', 'KS', 'KS', 'KS', 'KS', 'KS', 
    'KS', 'KS', 'KS', 'KS', 'NE', 'NE', '--', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 
    'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', 'LA', 'LA', 
    '--', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', '--', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 
    '--', 'AR', 'AR', 'AR', 'AR', 'AR', 'AR', 'AR', 'AR', 'AR', 'AR', 'AR', 'AR', 
    'AR', 'AR', 'OK', 'OK', '--', 'TX', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 
    'OK', '--', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 
    'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 
    'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 
    'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 
    'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 
    'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', '--', '--', 
    '--', 'WY', 'WY', 'WY', 'WY', 'WY', 'WY', 'WY', 'WY', 'WY', 'WY', 'WY', 'WY', 
    'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', '--', 'UT', 'UT', '--', 'UT', 'UT', 
    'UT', 'UT', 'UT', '--', '--', 'AZ', 'AZ', 'AZ', 'AZ', '--', 'AZ', 'AZ', 'AZ', 
    '--', 'AZ', 'AZ', '--', '--', 'AZ', 'AZ', 'AZ', '--', '--', '--', '--', 'NM', 
    'NM', '--', 'NM', 'NM', 'NM', '--', 'NM', 'NM', 'NM', 'NM', 'NM', 'NM', 'NM', 
    'NM', 'NM', '--', '--', '--', '--', 'NV', 'NV', '--', 'NV', 'NV', 'NV', '--', 
    'NV', 'NV', '--', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', '--', 
    'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 
    'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', '--', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 
    'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 
    'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 
    'AP', 'AP', 'AP', 'AP', 'AP', 'HI', 'HI', 'GU', 'OR', 'OR', 'OR', 'OR', 'OR', 
    'OR', 'OR', 'OR', 'OR', 'OR', 'WA', 'WA', 'WA', 'WA', 'WA', 'WA', 'WA', '--', 
    'WA', 'WA', 'WA', 'WA', 'WA', 'WA', 'WA', 'AK', 'AK', 'AK', 'AK', 'AK'
  ];

  $prefix = substr($zipcode, 0, 3);
  $index = intval($prefix); /* converts prefix to integer */
  return $zip_by_state[$index];
}
```

**This code on GIST:** 
https://gist.github.com/loureirorg/3f656d9a68494ab9fe7ca325cffd6f82

Comment: Thanks, Brad. That's a valid point. Unfortunately, there are 13 streets in the US where part of the street is in one state and the other part is in a different state.

I lived in a house that was in street between 2 towns. Most systems used to get the town wrong, lol, but it wasn't an big issue.

The only solution for this is to have the full address, to show something like "CA/OR" for these cases, or to just have this error.

The method I present above has the same accuracy as any other system (like google map) trying to resolve a state given a zip code.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the google api for this.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=77048

Just replace what's after address to the zip code you want and then extract the state name from the JSON.